# disable-randomization in gdb doesn't work

Tags: memory, gdb, aslr

The `gdb` variable `disable-randomization` is `ON`, but still the memory address of a variable changes on different run.

**First run:**

```
(gdb) p &g[v].bIsDummyVertex  
$13 = (bool *) 0x143d6a7c
```

**Second run:**

```
(gdb) p &g[v].bIsDummyVertex  
$13 = (bool *) 0x143d63e4
```

I was expecting the same value for the memory location because disable-randomization is on.

Comment: How is `g` declared? Array or pointer? Global scope or local to a function?

Comment: Also, what platform?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "g" is of type "boost::adjacency_list" . Hence it is basically graph data structure, g[v] returns vertex data structure. It is declared as class member and used in class function. The platform is linux 64 bits Red Hat Enterprise (Tikanga).

Comment: Something dynamically allocated can have a slightly different address each time unless conditions (such as the size and contents of the Unix environment string array) were exactly the same during each run. Were these two runs done with the same instance of gdb, or are they from two separate instances of gdb?

Comment: Thanks Mark. These runs are from same instance of gdb.